# Pull every other row, starting at 0, and concatenate them together

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a temp table that will contain two columns `ID` and `Text`. The temp table will contain an unknown amount of rows but there will always be an even amount. What I need to do is select every other row starting at 0 (so 0, 2, 4, 6, etc.) and then concatenate the values of `Text` together. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799816/return-row-of-every-nth-record which looks to be how to get every other row but I am not sure how to do the concatenation.

Example Table:

```
Row ID Text
0   0  This
1   1  Do
2   2  is
3   3  not
4   4  the
5   5  use
6   6  text
7   7  text
```

The result I would want from that table is `This is the text`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(ID INT, [Text] NVARCHAR(32));

INSERT @x VALUES (0,N'This'), (1,N'Do'),  (2,N'is'),   (3,N'not'), 
                 (4,N'the'),  (5,N'use'), (6,N'text'), (7,N'text');

SELECT LTRIM((SELECT ' ' + [Text] FROM 
  (SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID), [Text] FROM @x) AS x(rn, [Text])
  WHERE rn % 2 = 1 ORDER BY rn FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'));
```

Result:

```
This is the text
```

If you know your strings can't contain characters like `<`, `>` and `&` then it should be slightly more efficient to leave out the `TYPE).value` bit:

```
SELECT LTRIM((SELECT ' ' + [Text] FROM 
  (SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID), [Text] FROM @x) AS x(rn, [Text])
  WHERE rn % 2 = 1 ORDER BY rn FOR XML PATH('')));
```

Comment: Can you explain what `FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');` does and it's purpose?

Comment: `FOR XML PATH` is described lightly [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx). Essentially, it's a way to trick XML into performing string concatenation for us, but in a defined way (hence the `ORDER BY`). The `TYPE).value` stuff is just protection against strings like `'hey<man'` from messing up the XML formatting, `<` is also a special XML character.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
declare @tTable TABLE(ID INT identity, tText nvarchar(100));
declare @tString nvarchar(4000);

insert into @tTable VALUES
('This'),
('Do'),
('is'),
('not'),
('the'),
('use'),
('text'),
('text')

select @tString = COALESCE(@tString+' ','') + tText
from @tTable
where id%2 = 1

select @tString
```

Comment: This approach isn't guaranteed to concatenate them in the correct order. [Or to work at all in fact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior/15163136#15163136)

Comment: This worked perfectly and is much cleaner then the post I had linked to thanks.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete Please see the many quotes from Microsoft I compiled on the previous link. `Even without ORDER BY, we do not guarantee that @var = @var + will produce the concatenated value for any statement that affects multiple rows. The right-hand side of the expression can be evaluated either once or multiple times during query execution and the behavior as I said is plan dependent.`

Comment: @Matthew it may look cleaner but *it is not guaranteed to work*.

Comment: Ok in light of all the comments I have unmarked the answer and will now be testing @AaronBertrand post