# Not sure why code is failing when CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is set to OFF

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

In my question over at [Pull every other row, starting at 0, and concatenate them together](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51480/pull-every-other-row-starting-a-0-and-concatenate-them-together) user @AaronBertrand provided me with a chunk of code that worked fine in test but as soon as I put the procedure using the code into place and tested from the calling app I get an error.

> SELECT error: SELECT failed because the following SET options have
>   incorrect settings: 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL'

In testing if I set `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF` the procedure will fail when called from SSMS but if I set `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON` it works fine, further testing is showing the calling app to explicitly be setting `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF` and I can not override that. So I need to figure out how to update the code block to prevent this problem.

```
SELECT @TreeLocationStructure = STUFF (
    (
        SELECT ' -> ' + TreeLocation
        FROM (
            SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (ORDER BY ID), TreeLocation
            FROM #TreeSplit
        ) AS x(rn, TreeLocation)
        WHERE rn % 2 = 1
        ORDER BY rn FOR XML PATH,TYPE
    ).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1 ,4, ''
);
```

Comment: Why does the app set this setting explicitly in either direction? Also if the app is calling a stored procedure you can override what the app is setting *inside the procedure*.

Comment: I have no idea why the app is doing it, it is some huge 3rd party software. The only thing we get to do is write procs that it calls. I have seen the SET operators in a stored proc, would I just add them after the `CREATE PROC()AS` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your procedure to:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ProcedureName
  @Params ...
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;

  ... the rest of your code ...
END
GO
```

You might also want to get in touch with the vendor of the software, as changing this setting to `OFF` has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005, and soon the setting will have no effect or cause an error:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks once again you have helped me a great deal. I am not much of a SQL guy (I mostly work on the middle and front end using C# and MVC).